# Setting up CentOS for 3 or more network connections

Tags: centos

I am setting up a cluster for my company, and I want to find out whether is it possible to have three or more network connections active on a machine running CentOS 6.

I have `eth0` for the internal network, `eth1` for public network access and InfiniBand setup for IBoIP. The problem is that the InfiniBand is using one of the ports for IBoIP.

Comment: More of a question for ServerFault, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Three is peanuts. Linux is capable of having *hundreds* of interfaces active.